# Sass --watch not updating css

Tags: css, ruby, ubuntu, sass

I've installed Sass and set up a folder with an index.html file and style.scss in my local server (In Ubuntu 13.04).

I type this command into the terminal:

```
 sass --watch style.scss:style.css
```

And get this output:

> > > Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
> > >       LoadError: cannot load such file -- rb-inotify
> > >         Use --trace for backtrace.

Sass will update the css the first time I save my .scss file but after that nothing. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `rb-inotify` gem:

```
gem install rb-inotify
```

Answer (score 0):

Its more of code editor issue. I faced this issue with brackets and once I switched to Atom (just to test) sass started writing on css file real time.
Tried with both sass --watch sass:css (Directory based watch) and sass --watch sass/app.sass:css/app.css (file based), and both worked fine.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question - it would be more appropriate as a comment. See [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for answering questions here.